# File with .SCRIPT extension - Not running in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms, javax.script

I have a file named "CreateDatabase1.script".
I want to create a database from this file but this file is not executable in SQL
Server management studio. How can I run this file and create this database??

Comment: Without any information about the contents of the file nor any context, it is unlikely you will get help. Start by defining exactly what "not executable" means. There are many tools that will read files contains SQL statements and execute them. Do you have any? Do you have access to a SQL Server instance?

Comment: You need to associate the '.SCRIPT' file extension with SSMS Editor. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [associate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/associate-file-extensions-to-a-code-editor?view=sql-server-ver15#to-associate-a-new-file-extension-with-a-code-editor-in-sql-server-management-studio) a file extension with SSMS Editor.

[image]